# Object movement unit

Tags: objects

Can I set the unit to move when I press the G key and move the object? For example, can the box be set to move in a fixed unit by 5mm increments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the snapping unit by changing the grid scale:

[image]

Though, this is relative to the zoom level (relative to the grid).

To use it, make sure that snapping is set to "increment":

[image]

While grabbing, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to snap one unit and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> keys to snap 1/10 units.